# Get Cart Tax Total programmatically in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, tax

How do you get the tax total in WooCommerce in the **`functions.php`** page in WordPress,  Using :

```
global $woocommerce;

$discount = $woocommerce->cart->tax_total;
```

**But is not returning any value.**

How can I get Cart Tax Total?

Essentially I want the Tax to calculate for the user, but then have it reduced as the customer will pay the taxes on COD.

Full Code below:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'action_cart_calculate_totals', 10, 1 );
function action_cart_calculate_totals( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( !WC()->cart->is_empty() ):
        $cart_object->cart_contents_total *= .10 ;

    endif;
}


//Code for removing tax from total collected
function prefix_add_discount_line( $cart ) {

  global $woocommerce;

  $discount = $woocommerce->cart->tax_total;

  $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __( 'Tax Paid On COD', 'your-text-domain' ) , - $discount );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'prefix_add_discount_line' );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. **`global $woocommerce; $woocommerce->cart`** is obsolete for Cart. Use **`WC()->cart`** instead. 
   **Here you can use directly `$cart` *(object)* argument instead…**
2. The correct property is **`taxes`** instead of **`tax_total`**.
3. Is better to use [WC_Cart **get_taxes()**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_get_taxes) method intead to be compatible with WooCommerce version 3.0+

To achieve what you are trying to Your code is going to be:

```
// For Woocommerce 2.5+ (2.6.x and 3.0)
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'prefix_add_discount_line', 10, 1 );
function prefix_add_discount_line( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $discount = 0;
    // Get the unformated taxes array
    $taxes = $cart->get_taxes(); 
    // Add each taxes to $discount
    foreach($taxes as $tax) $discount += $tax;

    // Applying a discount if not null or equal to zero
    if ($discount > 0 && ! empty($discount) )
        $cart->add_fee( __( 'Tax Paid On COD', 'your-text-domain' ) , - $discount );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and works.

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong function name. Correct function is as below :-

```
WC()->cart->get_tax_totals( );
```

Instead of using $woocommerce->cart->tax_total; to get cart total tax, you can do this by subtracting cart total excluding tax from cart total.

You can do this by following code :-

```
$total_tax = floatval( preg_replace( '#[^\d.]#', '', WC()->cart->get_cart_total() ) ) - WC()->cart->get_total_ex_tax();
```

If you want to get array for all taxes then you can get through below code :-

```
WC()->cart->get_taxes( );
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use this function taht worked for me.

```
WC()->cart->get_total_tax();
```